# Connect to localhost from android device?

Tags: android, localhost

I have wifi on, connected to the network.

I disabled firewall, called ipConfig and tried the address, but nothing is connecting me to my localhost server. Anyone have a solution or things I can try still? I am on a Nexus 5 if that affects anything.

Comment: So your device is both client and server? How are you connecting? Socket? HTTPRequest?

Comment: I have localhost on my computer running by nodejs, and my android application on my android device. I am trying to test get/post requests but I am not getting anything on my server, but I am trying to even hit the browser from my device and it is not working